# Equality of length on R-modules implies isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, modules

Some time ago I found a theorem here at math.SE that states (under assumptions I can't recall):

> Let M and N be two R-Modules, if $l(M\otimes L)=l(N\otimes L)$ for all R-modules $L$ then $M\simeq N$

Here $l(A)$ stands for the length of the R-module A.
I have searched here alot but couldn't find any result that combines length and isomorphism. What am I asking for is for a reference of an article or book that provides me the conditions to make the above statement true.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: This is only true in rather trivial cases.  I suspect there are some more important details you have misremembered than just the needed assumptions.  In particular, the given assumption says nothing more than that $l(M)=l(N)$, since $l(M\oplus L)$ is always just $l(M)+l(L)$.

Comment: Maybe the direct sum is supposed to be a tensor product instead?  Then the condition would be reasonably strong and I could believe the result is true with some non-stupid hypotheses.

Comment: Relying on memory is often a bad idea. I will gratefully take your suggestion and change to tensor product.